# I want to limit of the number of image drop in an animation IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to objective c, I have created an app in which the bees will be dropping and a bear will try to catch them, everything is working fine. Now i want to limit of the number bees dropping to 20 or something, could anyone help me how to do that?

I'm not sure whether to put the timer in loop or the drop bee method in loop, any input in this will be highly helpful.

```
beeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(dropBee) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)dropBee
{
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
// CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

UIImageView *beeImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bee-honey.png"]];

int resultX = (int)roundf(screenWidth);
int randomX = 0 + rand()%(resultX -0);

[beeArray addObject:beeImage];
beeImage.frame = CGRectMake(50, -10, 50, 50);
beeImage.center = CGPointMake(randomX, 50);
[self.view addSubview:beeImage];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"beemovement" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

beeImage.center = CGPointMake(randomX, 600);
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you adding bees to your application? It would be useful to see some code. If you have a method which is something like `-(void)addABee` then you could create a variable to count the number of bees.

In your header file:

```
@interface SomeController : UIViewController {
    int _maxNumberOfBees;
}
```

Then in your implementation:

```
-(void)theMethodYouUseToCreateYourBeeArray {
    beeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(dropBee) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    _maxNumberOfBees = 20;
    // etc...
}

-(void)dropBee {
    if ([beeArray count] >= _maxNumberOfBees) { 
        // if the number of bees is greater than or equal to _maxNumberOfBees...
        NSLog(@"Too many bees!");
    } else {
        // add your bee to the scene
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        // etc etc etc...
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have added my code in the question, please go through that and let me know.